# Simplify the equation $16\cos^6(t) + 16\sin^6(t) + 48\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to simplify the equation

$$16\cos^6(t) + 16\sin^6(t) + 48\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)$$

The goal here is to prove that this can be simplified in a scalar value.

Thanks!

Comment: Write $\cos^2t=1-\sin^2t$ and express as a polynomial in $\sin t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{multline}16\cos^6(t)+16\sin^6(t)+48\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)=\\=16\bigl(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)\bigr)^3-48\bigl(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)\bigr)\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)+48\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)=\\=16,\end{multline}since $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I LOVE YOU!

However, could you clarify a few things for me? I understand that (cos^t+sin^t)^3 will be 1, but I don't understand how you can simplify the last two terms.

Comment: @willsmith $-48\bigl(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)\bigr)\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)+48\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)=-48\times1\times\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)+48\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)=0$. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

$$(\sin^2t)^3+(\cos^2t)^3=(\sin^2t+\cos^2t)^3-3\sin^2t\cos^2t(\sin^2t+\cos^2t)=?$$

Answer (score 2):

It is:
$$16((\cos^2t+\sin^2t)^3-3\sin^2t\cos^2t(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)+3\sin^2t\cos^2t)=16(1^3-0)=16.$$

Comment: Wow, you guys are truly awesome. This is the best community with the best users. Thanks you so much!

However, could you clarify a few things for me? I understand that (cos^t+sin^t)^3 will be 1, but I don't understand how you can simplify the last two terms.

Comment: There are two such sum of squares. $\color{red}{1}^3-3\sin^2t\cos^2t\cdot \color{red}{1}+3\sin^2t\cos^2t=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$(a^2+b^2)^3 = a^6 + 3a^4b^2 + 3a^2b^2 + b^6 \Rightarrow$

$ a^6+b^6 = (a^2+b^2)^3 - 3a^2b^2(a^2+b^2)$

Substituting $a=\sin(x)$ and $b=\cos(x)$:

$ \sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x) = (\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))^3 - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)) = \\
1 - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) \Rightarrow$

$ 16\sin^6(x)+16\cos^6(x) = 16 - 48\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) \Rightarrow$

$ 16\sin^6(x)+16\cos^6(x) + 48\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) = 16$